# how to fix this: cinnamon stopped. your system is running in fallback mode

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, cinnamon, crash

yesterday, I found out that the mint 13 xfce installation is acting different then before.
I noticed that my dad's account was not looking it should normally. I tried my mom's account and when logged in, an error message pops up: 
`cinnamon has stopped. Your system is running in fallback mode`

The popup message also asks if you want to restart cinnamon. This does not help, the same happens again.

I do not understand the error. I have mint xfce installed. Why do I get an error about cinnamon?

But more importantly: how can I fix this?

I have googled for it but did not find an answer for this.

Edit: 
I have checked the computer now. It appears as if the wrong DE was in use, as xuhdev suggested.
I found that a list of 9 different session options are available. I do not know where these 9 options come from.

This is the list with session options:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vozckzdoc9ik0o2/Foto%2021-12-14%2013%2035%2027.jpg?dl=0

Can I get rid of the most of these options to avoid future problems like the one described above?

Xuhdev: I have not received answers which I can accept..

Thanks everybody for commenting to help me out...

Comment: Did you log into Cinnamon or xfce? Maybe you just didn't pick the right desktop to log in.

Comment: cinnamon is not installed at all I believe. I only installed mint 13 xfce. I have not added another DE

Comment: Would you please post the output of `lshw -C video` or `lspci` as outlined in [this meta post](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3278/how-can-i-be-assured-that-my-issue-can-be-helped-here)